c# Unable to Auto Size all Combo Box Dropdown Column Widths on Windows Form
I have written the two below methods to auto size the dropdown widths of all the combo boxes on a windows form. However, it doesn't appear to be hitting any of the combo boxes. When I apply the method ComboBoxDropDownWidth to a single combo box under the form load event it works. To confirm, I also fire ComboBoxAutofitDropDownWidth(this) under the form load event.
public static int ComboBoxDropDownWidth(ComboBox comboBox)
{
    int maxWidth = 0;
    foreach (var obj in comboBox.Items)
    {
        int defaultWidth = TextRenderer.MeasureText(obj.ToString(), comboBox.Font).Width;
        if (defaultWidth > maxWidth)
        {
            maxWidth = defaultWidth;
        }
    }
    return maxWidth;
}

public static void ComboBoxAutofitDropDownWidth(Form form)
{
    var comboBoxes = form.Controls
          .OfType<ComboBox>();

    foreach (var comboBox in comboBoxes)
    {
        comboBox.DropDownWidth = ComboBoxDropDownWidth(comboBox);
    }
}



form.Controls will see all controls directly on the form. If you have other controls in between like panels, groupboxes etc. it won't see them. You should debug ComboBoxAutofitDropDownWidth and see yourself what controls actually end up in the comboBoxes variable.

Thank you thats helpful to know. The combo boxes are inside a group box. So I need to traverse all the controls and look inside, as I want this to work on any form.

Correct you may find examples for that en masse via google that recurse into the controls structure. Along the line of changing ComboBoxAutofitDropDownWidth to take a control instead of a form. And calling itself again if the current control isn't a Combox but has a non empty Controls Collection of its own.
